# C# web scraper navigate to aspx link

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping

I have a C# Windows Phone 8.1 app which I am building. Part of the app needs to go and look for information on a specific web page. One of the fields which I need is a URL which can be found on certain items on the page, however I am finding that the URL is in a relative-style format

```
FullArticle.aspx?a=323495
```

I am wondering if there is a way in C# using HtmlAgilityPack, HttpWebRequest etc etc to find the link to the actual page. Code snippet is below.

```
private static TileUpdate processSingleNewsItem(HtmlNode newsItemNode)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("");
    var articleImage = getArticleImage(getNode(newsItemNode, "div", "nw-container-panel-articleimage"));
    var articleDate = getArticleDate(getNode(newsItemNode, "div", "nw-container-panel-articledate"));
    var articleSummary = getArticleSummary(getNode(newsItemNode, "div", "nw-container-panel-textarea"));
    var articleUrl = getArticleUrl(getNode(newsItemNode, "div", "nw-container-panel-articleimage"));
    return new TileUpdate{
        Date = articleDate,
        Headline = articleSummary,
        ImagePath = articleImage,
        Url = articleUrl
    };
}

private static string getArticleUrl(HtmlNode parentNode)
{
    var imageNode = parentNode.Descendants("a").FirstOrDefault();
    Debug.WriteLine(imageNode.GetAttributeValue("href", null));
    return imageNode.GetAttributeValue("href", null);
}

private static HtmlNode getNode(HtmlNode parentNode, string nodeType, string className)
{
    var children = parentNode.Elements(nodeType).Where(o => o.Attributes["class"].Value == className);
    return children.First();
}
```

Would appreciate any ideas or solutions. Cheers!

Comment: If the links are in relative format, can't you just add the current URL as the prefix to obtain the full URL ? Maybe passing in `Reqest.AbsoluteUri` into `processSingleNewsItem` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my [web crawler](http://blog.abodit.com/2010/03/a-simple-web-crawler-in-c-using-htmlagilitypack/) here's what I do:

```
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//a[@href]"))
{
    HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];
    if (att == null) continue;
    string href = att.Value;
    if (href.StartsWith("javascript", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) continue;      // ignore javascript on buttons using a tags

    Uri urlNext = new Uri(href, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

    // Make it absolute if it's relative
    if (!urlNext.IsAbsoluteUri)
    {
        urlNext = new Uri(urlRoot, urlNext);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. I hadn't thought to look and see if the string was contained anywhere in the Url stupidly so your answer prompted me to check it and I found the string (and the rest of the Url I set to urlRoot in your example).